# Create an action for a button in xcode 13.2.1

Tags: applescript, applescript-objc

I am unable to create an action for a button using xcode 13.2.1 on macOS Monterey 12.1
has something changed or is this an xcode bug?
[Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnxbh.png)

Comment: Is the problem the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69446889/10853463)?

Comment: Yes, Any solution or just wait for Apple to fix the problem?

Comment: You can wait, do it programmatically, or [try running an older version of Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69995053/10853463).